# Vertical Tab Bars?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit, ios4, tabbar

I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find documentation or a tutorial on how to make a vertical tab bar for iOS like in [1Password](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1password-pro/id319898689?mt=8) or [2do](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/2do-stunning-todo-list/id303656546?mt=8).

I figure that these aren't "real" tab bars, but I'd really like to use that functionality and I'm at a loss on how to accomplish it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You know if I didn't know better it look like series of differently skinned buttons just next to the UITableView.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine the best way to go about it would be to populate a `UIView` with a bunch of `UIButton`s and style it like a `UITabBar`. To save time, you could take the code from [this custom tab bar](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/), and modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the link. Yes, I think this would be the easiest way to implement a vertical tab bar.

Comment: Link is dead, should include code from the link in answers.

Answer (score 2):

A vertical tab bar implementation for iPad can be found [here](https://github.com/nst/SEVerticalTabBar).

Answer (score 2):

Recently I created a simple implementation of vertical tab bar for iOS: https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController

Main goal was to mimic the original tab bar as closely as possible, but at the same time it's customizable and you have the code! :)

Comment: Why iOS 5 is a must? Any replace solution for the API that only exist in iOS5?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried to emulate UIViewController containment. It seems like a tricky task that could take lots of time and it still would be very bug prone. Then again, with iOS6 on horizon I don't think that there's any reason to support iOS4. It's not Android, people can upgrade the OS :)

Answer (score 2):

Recently I created a simple implementation of vertical tab bar for iOS: https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController It's more "modern" than SEVerticalTabBar as it uses UIViewController mechanism. The downside is that it requires iOS5.

Comment: The example references a non-esistent FSViewController