# iOS vertical tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I am trying to implement a vertical tab bar for an iphone application. I found a similar question at [Vertical Tab Bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552545/vertical-tab-bars) but the link provided in the solution does not exist anymore.

Appreciate it if anyone can give me an example of how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.