# Tab bar issue for iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'd like to display what looks like a vertical tab bar at left side as in, for example, Twitter app for iPad:

[image: Twitter]

1. Is that a `UISplitViewController` with a `UITabBar` within its left side?
2. Is it a tab bar with vertical orientation (if that is possible, I couldn't find such  property in UITabBar class...)?
3. Is it a custom tabBar-like control?
4. I've read some posts dealing with this (for instance, [iOS vertical tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698723/ios-vertical-tab-bar)), that were written some time ago, does this issue remain the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom tabbar controls are available. I think [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cksidebarcontroller) will fit with your requirements.